# Get a dynamic range in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that takes a table's range and then emails it every day. Currently it is set up to get a fixed range (G2:H38). The process currently works, but every day I send the email, I have a handful of blank cells that are also sent out.  I am new to this and hoping someone can help me solve for this.

```
var rowData = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "example@gmail.com";
    var recipient = rowData[0];
    var yesterdayDate = rowData[5];
    var message1 = rowData[2] + yesterdayDate;
    var message2 = rowData[3]
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var data = sh.getRange("G2:H38").getValues();
    //var htmltable =[];
    var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;display:table;max-width:400px;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;margin-top:30px'
    var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';
    var tablehead = 'style="background-color:#6aa84f;color:white;';

      for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){
        htmltable += '<tr>';
      for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
        if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';} 
          else
            if (row === 0)  {
              htmltable += '<th ' + tablehead +' ">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
            }

          else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
      }
     htmltable += '</tr>';
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second `for` loop, first condition catches and appends empty table cells for cell values that have no data in them. Adding a `0` check does not help here as you should check for `data[row][col]===0` if you want to match values that equal `0`, not `||0`.

Otherwise, your code works as intended and testing it on a sample `Spreadsheet` works - "if cell in Range is empty, append empty cell to table". Do you want to filter out all empty cells?

### Update

I am still unsure why you would like to filter out empty cells from the `HtmlTable`, but if you want only the ones with data to be shown, change your `if...else` statement a little to account for that:

```
if (row===0&&data[0][col]!=='')  { //filter out empty header cells;
  htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
}else if(data[row][col]!=='') { //filter out empty entries cells
  htmltable += '<td style="border:1px solid black;">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I'm very new to this and still learning all of the syntax. How would I go about filtering out the empty cells? The email that is sent out, shows all of the correct data, but it also still shows all of the empty cells.

Comment: NP! I am still not sure what you are trying to do (actually, more like why), but do take a look at the updated answer in a couple of minutes from now - this should filter out empty cells.